# noob python question, extract letter from list

Tags: python

not sure why this isn't working.
error I'm getting: `ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found`

code:

```
phrase =  'test'
number = 0
text = 0
random1 = ''

while (number <= len(phrase)):

    letter = phrase[number:number+1]

    text = ord(letter) - ord('a')
    ....
    number = number + 1
```

if a print letter, i get the `t` for the first iteration

thanks,

Comment: I don't see an `i` in there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are failing on your last iteration.  Because you let number take the value `len(phrase)`, you are trying to slice your string beyond the end.

For example:

```
>>> "abc"[3:4]
''
```

String indices range from 0 to len(s)-1.

BTW: Python gives you much nicer ways to iterate over strings:

```
phrase = 'test'
for letter in phrase:
    text = ord(letter) - ord('a')
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating past the end of phrase, try this:

```
phrase =  'test'
number = 0
text = 0
random1 = ''

while (number < len(phrase)):

    letter = phrase[number:number+1]

    text = ord(letter) - ord('a')
```

Note the:

```
while (number < len(phrase)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a char and not a string, right?  Try to replace your

```
letter = phrase[number:number+1]
```

with

```
letter = phrase[number]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed have to show more code. What is i? Are you incrementing it each loop?

Typically, if you ARE incrementing i to act just like a for loop, you want to loop such that number < len(phrase), not <=.

Also, you can replace

letter = phrase[number:number+1]

with

letter = phrase[number]

Answer (score 0):

Use `for..in` instead to process each letter in your string:

**Code**:

```
phrase = 'test'
for letter in phrase:
   print letter
```

**Output**:

```
t
e
s
t
```

This would be the more "pythonic" way of doing character iteration. This way you're guaranteed to hit every letter without having to consider hitting the end, as what's happening in your code.